# Algo question: iterating over multiple time series "as of"

Tags: algorithm

This question is not language specific.

Suppose I have N time-series named S_1, S_2, ... S_N. What I mean by time series is something like (schematically)

```
struct timeseries{T}
    values::Vector{T}
    timestamps::Vector{Timestamp}
end
```

where the two vectors have same length for each time-series.

You cannot assume that the time-series have the same number of elements. For a day worth of data, some of the time-seres might have millions of elements where others might have a couple of elements, but you can assume they all fit in memory simultaneously. You can assume all time-series are sorted in timestamps.

I would like to obtain another time-series which:

- has as many timestamps as the union of the timestamps of the N time-series
- for each timestamp `t` its value is a tuple of the values of the N time-series at a time less or equal `t`, when they exist and NaN `otherwise`

So for example, imagine we have two time-series which I represent as a list of tuples (timestamp,values):

```
S_1 = [(1,43),(4,20),(5,21),(10,10)]
S_2 = [(2,31),(4,-5),(6,-1),(11,100)]
```

The result would be:

```
[(1,43,NaN),(2,43,31),(4,20,-5),(5,21,-5),(6,21,-1),(10,10,-1),(11,10,100)]
```

Comment: you mean, the new series will have two values instead of one?

Comment: In the example, yes. In general it will have N values. Or one values which is a N-tuple, whatever you prefer.

Comment: I'm asking because it makes a difference - in the example, you include the two closest timestamps from the left, for each time t. That makes the problem harder than in case if for example we could include ANY two timestamps from the left, or include all timestamps from the left

Comment: And by the way, should the values inside of new tuples be sorted by timestamps or they may come in any order? In the example they come in arbitrary order

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by including timestamps "from the left". Inside the new tuples the values are sorted depending on which of the original time-series they belong to. So of the resulting series you have (timestamp, value from series 1, values from series 2). How you organize the results is not really the point.

Comment: by saying "from the left" I meant from the left side of chronological axis i.e. previous t's. I have posted one possible solution below, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

This is easy if you have one useful data structure.

That data structure is a *priority queue*.  You stick things into a priority queue, and they come out in order of the priority.  So we can make our `n` time series into `n` tuples of `(timestamp, queue, position, timeseries)`.  They will come out sorted first by `timestamp`, and then by `queue`.  There are no other ties.

For priority queues implemented with a heap data structure, inserting is `O(log(n))`, removing the head is `O(log(n))` and merely reading the head is `O(1)`.

And now we have an algorithm as follows:

```
# Initialize
Take our n timeseries, make n tuples (timestamp, queue, 0, timeseries)
Put the tuples into a priority queue
set last_timestamp = the timestamp of the first element in the queue.
set answer = [[last_timestamp, NaN, NaN, ..., NaN]]
set current_vector = answer[0]

# Work
while priority queue is not empty:
    (timestamp, queue, position, timeseries) = pop off of queue
    if timestamp = last_timestamp:
        current_vector = copy of current_vector
        current_vector[0] = timestamp
        answer.append(current_vector)
        last_timestamp = timestamp

    # Update for this record
    current_vector[queue] = timeseries[position][1]
    position = position + 1
    if position < len(timeseries):
        append to queue (timeseries[position][0], queue, position, timeseries)
```

If you have `n` timeseries, `m` timestamps, and `k` total entries, this algorithm will take `O(n*m + k*log(n))`.  (The first term is from creating new entries for the answer, the second is processing each timeseries entry.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. What are you putting into the queue? All datapoint of all series? Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but if you have the same timestamp on two different time-series, those will produce two resulting datapoints with the same timestamp, correct? That's not what I want. If two or more series have 1 timestamp in common that should only produce one resulting timestamp (see my example, timestamp 4. Also, one put and one pop per loop isn't great. Might me ok for large N, but for small N it's terrible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the solution looks for me (assuming that we include closest two timestamps from series1 and series2):

1. prepare two binary search trees, one for series1, one for series2. let's call them bst1 and bst2. (bst entry consists of timestamp and value)
2. scan through the timestamps of both series and put timestamps into the hashset. then sort the hashset values. in your example, the sorted keys will be [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 10, 11 ]
3. iterate through the sorted list of timestamps, and do following:

   - check the timestamp for presence in bst1. if it is in bst1, then include it into the new tuple for the new series. if it is not in bst1, find its immediate predecessor in bst1. if there is no predecessor, include NaN into the new tuple.
   - check the timestamp for presence in bst2. if it is in bst2, then include it into the new tuple for the new series. if it is not in bst2, find its immediate predecessor in bst2. if there is no predecessor, include NaN into the new tuple.
   - add new tuple into the new series

Comment: And if there are 100 time series...?

Comment: you're right, i missed the fact that the number of series could be larger than two. the priority queue solution is much neater, I should have realized it prior to posting the answer))

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a fairly straightforward merge operation. You start off with a tuple containing all NaN values, for as many timeseries as you have:

```
{NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN}
```

Put an iterator at the start of each sorted timeseries, and look at the elements they point to to find the first timestamp among them:

```
TS1: {(2,a),(3,b),(7,c)}
       ^
TS2: {(6,d),(12,e)}
       ^
TS3: {(1,f),(3,g),(5,h)}
       ^
TS4: {(4,i),(5,j),(8,k),(10,l),(12,m),(14n)}
       ^
```

The first timestamp at the iterators is 1 in timeseries 3, so we update its value in the tuple:

```
{NaN,NaN,f,NaN}
```

and add the tuple to the total timeseries with the current timestamp:

```
TS: {(1, {NaN,NaN,f,NaN})}
```

and we increment the iterator for timeseries 3 and move on:

```
TS1: {(2,a),(3,b),(7,c)}
       ^
TS2: {(6,d),(12,e)}
       ^
TS3: {(1,f),(3,g),(5,h)}
             ^
TS4: {(4,i),(5,j),(8,k),(10,l),(12,m),(14n)}
       ^
```

The first timestamp is now 2 in timeseries 1, so we update its value in the tuple:

```
{a,NaN,f,NaN}
```

and add the tuple to the total timeseries with the current timestamp:

```
TS: {(1, {NaN,NaN,f,NaN}), (2, {a,NaN,f,NaN})}
```

In the next step we see that there are two identical first timestamps at the location of the iterators:

```
TS1: {(2,a),(3,b),(7,c)}
             ^
TS2: {(6,d),(12,e)}
       ^
TS3: {(1,f),(3,g),(5,h)}
             ^
TS4: {(4,i),(5,j),(8,k),(10,l),(12,m),(14n)}
       ^
```

so we update the value of both timeseries 1 and 3 in the tuple:

```
{b,NaN,g,NaN}
```

and add the tuple to the total timeseries with the current timestamp:

```
TS: {(1, {NaN,NaN,f,NaN}), (2, {a,NaN,f,NaN}), (3, {b,NaN,g,NaN})}
```

and increment both iterators:

```
TS1: {(2,a),(3,b),(7,c)}
                   ^
TS2: {(6,d),(12,e)}
       ^
TS3: {(1,f),(3,g),(5,h)}
                   ^
TS4: {(4,i),(5,j),(8,k),(10,l),(12,m),(14n)}
       ^
```

And so on...

The advantage of this method is that it doesn't use additional data structures, just iterators over the timeseries. If creating an additional data structure is no problem, then use btilly's answer. If you have a large number of dataseries, you'd have to use something like a priority queue to find the first timestamp anyway, so then you basically have btilly's answer.

Comment: This definitely works.  But if there are so many timeseries that we can't afford to create a priority queue, then looping over the timeseries is likely to be a performance issue...

Comment: @btilly Yes, I have no idea what kind of numbers are involved. If there are a large number of timeseries, then repeatedly finding the minimum timestamp (and possible duplicates) will be time-consuming. Maybe putting just the top element of each series in a much smaller priority queue could be the solution to that problem.

Comment: @m69 At which point it is morally the same as the solution that I gave.  The most important difference being that you're using an iterator while I'm passing both `position` and `timeseries` then using them together as an iterator.

Comment: @btilly Oops, I hadn't looked closely enough at your answer, I thought you were proposing to put all of the data into a huge priority queue.